# Linking to documentation in a comment

Tags: vimscript, help-system

I'd like to provide anyone reading my plugin in Vim a direct link to the help article on [`command-completion`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command-completion)

At the moment, I'm simply saying `" :help command-completion` but i'd love to do something like`" |command-completion|` to allow a user to navigate directrly with `C-]`. I've tried a few random combinations but nothing seems to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're following the advice in the Vim help pages ([`:h write-local-help`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write-local-help)) and formatting your links with double-stars and double-bars in the Vim style.  However, for vim to recognize them as tags, you have to set the `iskeyword` option correctly, namely

```
:set iskeyword=!-~,^*,^\|,^\"
```

The way Vim does this for its own help files is to use a modeline.  For an example of this, type `:help` and go to the last line in the help window. Finally, you'll have to create a `tags` file for your plugin.  Use the [`:helptags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#%3Ahelptags) command for that.